# Allow specific coupons when there is backordered items in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, coupon

Is it possible to allow a certain woocommerce coupon only on backorders?

I've tried to use [If WooCommerce Cart items are on backorder do not apply coupon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641987/if-woocommerce-cart-items-are-on-backorder-do-not-apply-coupon/45642125#45642125) answer code that restricts backordered products from using any coupons.

I have changed `if( $stock_info < 1 ){` to  `if( $stock_info > 0 ){` instead

But then I can only use coupons on backorders… but where do I make this work on a certain coupon?

May I use its ID? but where?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will make specific defined coupons codes valid when there is backordered items in cart:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_is_valid', 'specific_coupons_valid_for_backorders', 10, 3 );
function specific_coupons_valid_for_backorders( $is_valid, $coupon, $discount ){
    // HERE below define in the array your coupon codes
    $coupon_codes = array( 'summer', 'tenpercent' );

    if( in_array( $coupon->get_code(), $coupon_codes ) ) {
        $is_valid = false;

        // Loop through cart items and check for backordered items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if( $cart_item['data']->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                $is_valid = true; // Backorder found, coupon is valid
                break; // Stop and exit from the loop
            }
        }
    }
    return $is_valid;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.